# React-chartjs not working

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm trying to use react-chartjs within my project, but it doesn't seem to work...

I'm using react-router to load this page (home):

```js
import React from 'react';
import { TextField, RaisedButton } from 'material-ui';
import { History } from 'react-router';
import Chart from './widgets/Chart.js';


const Home = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
        };
    },

    componentDidMount() {
    },

    toggleNotification() {

    },

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <Chart/>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

export default Home;
```

and Chart refers to this file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Chart from 'chart.js';
import {LineChart} from 'react-chartjs';

function rand(min, max, num) {
    var rtn = [];
    while (rtn.length < num) {
        rtn.push((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
    }
    return rtn;
}

const ChartWidget = React.createClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            chartData : {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data: [5, 8, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0]
                },
                {
                    label: "My Second dataset",
                    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    data: [-2, -5, 0, -3, -1, 0, -1]
                }
            ]
        }};
    },

    componentDidMount() {
    },

    toggleNotification() {

    },

    render() {
        return (
                <LineChart data={this.state.chartData} redraw width="600" height="250" />
        )
    }
});

export default ChartWidget;
```

Error I'm getting:
`Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of`ChartWidget`.warning @ vendor.bundle.js:11125ReactElementValidator.createElement @ vendor.bundle.js:27927render @ app.bundle.js:29792(anonymous function) @ app.bundle.js:407ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext @ vendor.bundle.js:14599ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:14619wrapper @ vendor.bundle.js:11394ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:14232wrapper @ vendor.bundle.js:11394ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:12542ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren @ vendor.bundle.js:22652ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup @ vendor.bundle.js:19830ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:19718ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:12542ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:14237wrapper @ vendor.bundle.js:11394ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:12542ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren @ vendor.bundle.js:22652ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup @ vendor.bundle.js:19830ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:19718ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:12542ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren @ vendor.bundle.js:22652ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup @ vendor.bundle.js:19830ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:19718ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:12542ReactMultiChild.Mixin.mountChildren @ vendor.bundle.js:22652ReactDOMComponent.Mixin._createContentMarkup @ vendor.bundle.js:19830ReactDOMComponent.Mixin.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:19718ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:12542ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:14237wrapper @ vendor.bundle.js:11394ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:12542ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:14237wrapper @ vendor.bundle.js:11394ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:12542ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:14237wrapper @ vendor.bundle.js:11394ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:12542ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:14237wrapper @ vendor.bundle.js:11394ReactReconciler.mountComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:12542mountComponentIntoNode @ vendor.bundle.js:8912Mixin.perform @ vendor.bundle.js:13649batchedMountComponentIntoNode @ vendor.bundle.js:8928Mixin.perform @ vendor.bundle.js:13649ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates @ vendor.bundle.js:19229batchedUpdates @ vendor.bundle.js:13154ReactMount._renderNewRootComponent @ vendor.bundle.js:9122wrapper @ vendor.bundle.js:11394ReactMount._renderSubtreeIntoContainer @ vendor.bundle.js:9196ReactMount.render @ vendor.bundle.js:9216wrapper @ vendor.bundle.js:11394(anonymous function) @ app.bundle.js:280(anonymous function) @ app.bundle.js:285(anonymous function) @ app.bundle.js:286__webpack_require__ @ vendor.bundle.js:1051fn @ vendor.bundle.js:596(anonymous function) @ app.bundle.js:7__webpack_require__ @ vendor.bundle.js:1051webpackJsonpCallback @ vendor.bundle.js:22(anonymous function) @ app.bundle.js:1
vendor.bundle.js:9781 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of`ChartWidget`.`

Can only tell me what I did wrong?

Using:
Webpack
Hotloaders
React.js
React-router
react-chartjs
material-ui

Comment: You should give React Chart.js 2 a try

Answer (score -3):

Try to import your *LineChart* this way instead:

`const LineChart = require('react-chartjs').Line;`

and remove:

`import {LineChart} from 'react-chartjs';`

Comment: it will change absolutely nothing.

`import {Line as LineChart} from 'react-chartjs'`
do exactly the same.